# Override a method & append new items to an existing dictionary Odoo13

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

I have overridden a method to append some new items to the dictionary of the original method. when I execute my code I have this error:

```
'bool' object has no attribute 'dict_one'
```

but the original method has that  attribute here is my code:

```
    def action_transaction_done(self):
        res = super(ProjectTransaction, self).action_transaction_done()

        res.dict_one['branch_id'] = self.branch_id.id
        return res
```

and this the orginal method code:

```
    def action_transaction_done(self):

        for action in self:
        
            for line in action.details_by_category:
            
                if self.account_id:
                    dict_one= (0, 0, {
                       'name': line.name,
                       'partner_id': line._get_partner_id(credit_account=False),
                       'account_id': self.account_id,
                       'journal_id': action.journal_id.id,
                       'date': date,
                       #to be added here
                    
                       })
                       return dict_one
```

I want to append this new item the dict

Comment: I'm not sure that the code you've posted is complete or matches the error message. Based on the error message, `super(ProjectTransaction, self).action_transaction_done()` is returning a `bool` type (True or False), but the code you've shown doesn't return that type. That in mind, a few things to note: the "original" code returns a tuple (if certain conditions hold). The third item in the tuple is a dictionary. You would access this dictionary with `res[2]`. But note that if the right conditions aren't met, `res` will be `None`, and you will get a different `AttributeError`.

Comment: so how to append a new item to the dictionary from the overridden method @captnsupremo

Comment: Can you explain what does `action_transaction_done` function do and what it should return?

Comment: it should return this tuple "dict_one", as you can see the third item of the tuple is a dictionary. My problem here, I  just want to add a new item to this dictionary which is the the third item of the tuple from my code. First of all, it is in a custom module and I am also working on another custom module that inherits from the first one, the method has been overridden in many places and each time does something different, this time I want to add an item to the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

When `account_id` (self.account_id) is not set, `action_transaction_done` will return `None`, to avoid the none type, check the returned result then add the branch to the returned tuple.

***Example:***

```
if res: 
    res[-1]['branch_id'] = self.branch_id.id
```

The following error:

```
'bool' object has no attribute 'dict_one'
```

Is not raised because of the original function.

The method has been overridden in many places, try to check those functions and check which one returns a boolean

Comment: now it throwing this error  'bool' object is not subscriptable.

Comment: how it can place it inside the dictionary using this  res[-1]['branch_id'] = self.branch_id.id

Comment: the dictionary is the third item in the tuple, don't you think it should happen first by reaching the tuple and then the dict

Comment: `res[-1]` is the last item in the tuple which is the dictionary and ``res`` is the tuple